# How to write conditional expectation as integral with respect to regular conditional distribution

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, expected-value, change-of-variable, geometric-measure-theory

> Can I write a conditional expectation as an integral with respect to a regular conditional distribution?

#### Set Up

- $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ probability space
- $(\mathsf{E}, \mathcal{E})$ measurable space with reference measure $\lambda_{\mathcal{E}}$
- $X:\Omega\to\mathsf{E}$ random variable with $\mathbb{E}[|X|] < \infty$ and distribution $P_X = X_*\mathbb{P}$ with $P_X \ll \lambda_{\mathcal{E}}$ and density $p_x = dP_X / d\lambda_{\mathcal{E}}$
- $\mathcal{G}\subseteq \mathcal{F}$ sub-sigma algebra
- $\nu:\mathsf{E}\times\mathcal{F}\to[0, 1]$ is a regular conditional probability. In other words a kernel satisfying
  $$
  \mathbb{P}(\mathsf{A}\cap X^{-1}(\mathsf{B})) = \int_{\mathsf{B}} \nu(x, A) P_x(dx)
  $$
- $h:\mathsf{E}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a sufficiently well-behaved function (probably measurable?)

#### Claim

According to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_probability) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Measure-theoretic_formulation) it is possible to write $\mathbb{E}[h(X) \mid \mathcal{G}]$ as an integral of $h(X)$ with respect to the regular conditional probability.
$$
\mathbb{E}[h(X) \mid \mathcal{G}] = \int_? h \circ X\,\, \nu(?, ?)
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Suppose $\nu : \Omega \times \mathcal{E} \to [0, 1]$ is a regular conditional distribution of $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$. This means that

1. For every $\omega \in \Omega$, $\nu(\omega, \cdot)$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal{E}$.
2. For every $A \in \mathcal{E}$, $\nu(\cdot, A)$ is $\mathcal{G}-\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ measurable.
3. For every $A \in \mathcal{E}$, $P(X \in A \mid \mathcal{G})(\omega) = \nu(\omega, A)$ for a.e. $\omega \in \Omega$.

Condition 3 says that for any $A \in \mathcal{E}$,
$$E(1_A(X) \mid \mathcal{G})(\omega) = \int_{E}1_{A}(x)\nu(\omega, dx) \hspace{20pt} \text{ for a.e. } \omega \in \Omega.$$
By nonnegative linearity of conditional expectations and integrals we get that for any simple function $f : (E, \mathcal{E}) \to [0, \infty)$,
$$E(f(X) \mid \mathcal{G})(\omega) = \int_{E}f(x)\nu(\omega, dx) \hspace{20pt} \text{ for a.e. } \omega \in \Omega.$$
Then for a measurable $f : E \to [0, \infty)$ with $E(f(X)) < \infty$, take a sequence of simple functions $f_n \to f$ and apply the previous result and the monotone convergence theorem for conditional expectations and integration to deduce the result for this $f$. Then apply linearity to deduce the result for real valued $f$ with $E(|f(X)|) < \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you mind expanding a bit about why condition 3 leads to the first integral you wrote? I suppose I am a bit confused by your writing of definition 3 and how you write the expectation with respect to the kernel rather than $\mathbb{P}$

Comment: @Euler_Salter By definition, $P(X \in A \mid \mathcal{G}) = E(1_{\{X \in A\}} \mid \mathcal{G})$. $1_{\{X \in A\}} = 1_A(X)$ is elementary since $\omega \in \{X \in A\}$ if and only if $X(\omega) \in A$. By definition, when $\mu$ is a measure, $\mu(A) = \int 1_A(x) \mu(dx)$. I think the point of regular conditional probability is to be able to write conditional expectations as actual expectations with respect to a measure. It's a generalization of the Baye's approach to conditional distributions in the discrete and continuous cases. Some references are Klenke's book and Durrett's book.